# 基礎となる言語はローカライズファイルを新たに作る必要はない？

Tags: ios, xcode

XcodeでiOSアプリを作っています。
そのアプリは英語と日本語をサポートし、その他のシステム言語で表示する時は英語で表示したいと思っています。

その為、ローカライズが必要なファイルの`File inspector` → `Localization`として`Base`、`Japanese`、`English`にそれぞれチェックを入れています。`Base`の内容は`English`と同等です。

この時、`Base`があるだけですでに英語として表示されるのなら`English`にチェックを入れなくても良いんじゃないかと思うのですが、リリースする時など何か不都合はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自分が作ったアプリなどはEnglishなしのBaseとJapaneseだけにしてリリースしてます。それで問題はなさそうです。

アプリのリリースには関係ないと思いますが、元からあったもしくは追加したローカライズを削除して実機でデバッグ実行するとそれらのリソースファイルが残ってしまって表示に正しく反映されないことがありました。その時はCleanしたりアプリを一旦削除してから実行したりして回避していました。(最新のXcodeでは起きない現象かもしれません)

Answer (score 2):

info.plistのLocalization native development regionが、enになっていることの確認も必要だと思います。
　開発用Macのregionを私は、トラブルを避けるために、USにしています。JPにしている人が、Xcodeで、プロジェクト生成した際に、作られる、info.plistが、なんなのかは、要確認だと思われます。